# Removing columns based on status using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I performed a series of experiments, whereupon completion I realized that a certain number of them are not reliable, so I would like to remove them. I decided to add another array, `status`, for this purpose, in which the columns I would like to keep are defined as `True`, whereas the ones I want to remove are denoted as `False`.

```
import numpy as np

data_a = np.arange(1,14)
status = np.array([False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True])

test = []
for stats, da in zip(status, data_a):
    if stats == True:
        data_a = da
        test.append(data_a)
    elif stats == False:
        pass
    else:
        print('Impossible -- in the case of status, there exist only two conditionals (True or False).')
```

In the most simple case, there are no problems, and it appears to work as intended by providing the following output:

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13]
```

However, I am working with several datasets (not only one, in this case, `data_a`). So I decided to make it a bit more difficult by adding two new arrays:

```
data_b = np.arange(101,114)
data_c = np.arange(1001,1014)

test = []
for datasets in (data_a, data_b, data_c):
    for stats, sets in zip(status, datasets):
        if stats == True:
            datasets = sets
            test.append(datasets)
        elif stats == False:
            pass
        else:
            print('Impossible -- in the case of status, there exist only two conditionals (True or False).')
```

This slightly more complicated case provides:

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 111, 112, 113, 1002, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1011, 1012, 1013]
```

It did what I asked for it, but what do I need to do in order for `data_a`, `data_b`, and `data_c` to be stored as arrays independently?

In most complicated case (and also realistic for what I am actually doing), my datasets are actually arrays of with shape `(11,13)`:

```
data_a = []
data_b = []
data_c = []

for dtlsts in (data_a, data_b, data_c):
    for _ in range(11):
        dtlsts.append(np.random.randint(0, 10, 13))

data_a = np.array(data_a)
data_b = np.array(data_b)
data_c = np.array(data_c)
```

Thus, I would like to:

- Remove the columns based on the status array, so I end up with arrays with shape `(11,10)`.
- Store these arrays independently (i.e. `data_a`, `data_b`, and `data_c` are all stored in independent `(11,10)` arrays).

I am on deep water, and would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you consider using `ma.masked_array(data_a,status)`? Requires `import numpy.ma as ma`

Comment: I would suggest using your boolean array as a mask, e.g. `data_a[status]` should return what you need. If you need rows from a 2d array, then use `your_array[:, status]` to return the all the rows and the required columns.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. I cannot believe I did not think about that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question you can do something like this:

```
test = [ [] for _ in range(3) ]
for i, state in enumerate(status):
  if state:
    test[0].append(data_a[i])
    test[1].append(data_b[i])
    test[2].append(data_c[i])

print(test)
#=> [[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13], [102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 111, 112, 113], [1002, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1011, 1012, 1013]]
```

Comment: Thank you, iGian. This is an informative solution that taught me how to think in Python. Do you have any idea how I would need to alter it in order for it work with 2D-arrays?

Comment: Can you provide an example of input/output?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Andrew's comment, you can index whole columns with a boolean mask like this.

```
In [120]: data_a = np.arange(1,14)
     ...: status = np.array([False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True])
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [121]: data_a
Out[121]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13])
In [122]: data_a[status]
Out[122]: array([ 2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 11, 12, 13])
```

For a 2d array, adjust the indexing:

```
In [123]: data_b = np.vstack([data_a,data_a,data_a])
In [124]: data_b[:,status]
Out[124]: 
array([[ 2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 11, 12, 13]])
```

Comment: Thank you once again, hpaulj. I feel stupid for not being able to come up with this myself.